# Set index name of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    ''     count
sugar      420
milk       108
vanilla    450
...
```

The first column has no header and I would like to give it the name: 'ingredient'.

I created the dataframe from a csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/file_name.csv', index_col=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")  
df = df['ingredient_group']  #selecting column 
df = df.value_counts()       #calculating string occurance which return series obj
df = pd.DataFrame(df)        #creating dataframe from series obj
```

How do I assign the name 'ingredient' to the first column which has currently no name?

I already tried:

```
df_count.rename(columns={'': 'ingredient'}, inplace=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['ingredient','count']
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

```
''        count
ingredient  ''
sugar      420
milk       108
vanilla    450
...
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

if ingredients is the name of the index then you can set it by

```
df.index.name='ingredient'
```

With the current solutions you have 'ingredient' as name of the index, which is printed in different row to that of column names. This cannot be changed as is.  Try the modified solution below, here the index is copied on to a new column with column name and the index replaced with sequence of numbers.

```
df['ingredient']=df.index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for how to set the name 'ingredient' of the AXIS for the Index.

```
df.rename_axis('ingredient', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cols_ = df.columns
cols[0] = 'ingredient'
df.columns = cols_
```

Comment: Dmitry thanks for your answer! Do you know how I can remove the rows from my dataframe with a count smaller than 5?

Comment: that would df[df.count > 5]