# Change name of index column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rename

im curious if I can change the name of my very first column which is counting auto incrementally the index.

I saw that you can change the name of the first column which is called `Unnamed 0` with this code
`df_new.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'newName'}, inplace=True )`

but this time there is no name which is called `Unnamed 0`

this is my output

```
      VPN Code    pid  VTS/VTA  ...  BSCL52_BL  BSCL53_BL  timepoint
0          IA1    1_1        1  ...          2          4          1
1          AI7    1_2        1  ...          3          2          1
2         RE11    1_3        1  ...          1          2          1
3     EA11/EA4    1_4        1  ...          1          2          1
4          UA2    1_5        1  ...        -33        -33          1
```

and i want to have something like this .... so with the `ID`

```
ID    VPN Code    pid  VTS/VTA  ...  BSCL52_BL  BSCL53_BL  timepoint
0          IA1    1_1        1  ...          2          4          1
1          AI7    1_2        1  ...          3          2          1
2         RE11    1_3        1  ...          1          2          1
3     EA11/EA4    1_4        1  ...          1          2          1
4          UA2    1_5        1  ...        -33        -33          1
```

anyone who could help me and tell me whats wrong ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Its answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968730/set-index-name-of-pandas-dataframe/37968994

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set index name of pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968730/set-index-name-of-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Does `df.index.name = 'ID'` work?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to change the name of the index, not a column, be careful as they are not the same! You are using a single index, therefore you can simple use `.index.names`:

`df.index.names = ['ID']`

Otherwise if it's actually a column, then you can certainly use `.rename(columns={'original_name','new_name'})` and in the case you are not sure the name of the column, but certain of it's position, you can get the name with `df.columns[0]` in this case. Keep in mind that this **Does not seem to be the problem** with the data you are sharing. I would use:

```
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:'ID'})
```